# ember-cli --proxy works for GET but fails on PUT and POST

Tags: ember.js, proxy, ember-cli

I'm trying to move my application from Ember Appkit to ember-cli and I'm having trouble replicating the proxy functionality previously provided by the APIMethod and proxyURL methods.

I'm starting the server to proxy to localhost:3000

`ember serve --proxy http://localhost:3000/`

This will read my data from the rails server correctly.  However, when I try to write to the server, I get an error message

`POST http://localhost:4200/api/v1/posts 408 (Request Time-out)`

It's trying to post to port 4200, which is where the ember app is being served, but I want it to post to port 3000. How can I get it to do so?

I'm using ember-cli 0.28, ember 1.5.1, ember-data 1.0.0-beta.7, and rails 4.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution was to comment out `app.use(bodyParser());` in server/index.js

Comment: Works indeed! Could you also post a explanation why `app.use(bodyParser());` should be commented out to work with PUT/POST properly?

Comment: @JacobvanLingen That would be a great subject for a source dive and an associated blog post.  I wish you luck in writing it.

Comment: I'm on .46 and this doesn't seem to be working for me. Any ideas why?