# ember-cli 0.46 --proxy fails on POST and PUT

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

This is already been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856465/ember-cli-proxy-works-for-get-but-fails-on-put-and-post) but the solution doesn't seem to be working for me.

There's some background [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/725). I've tried many things but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and found that it had something to do with my old mocks setup in server/index.js. I'm not using mocks at the moment so I just deleted the entire server directory and that cleared it up. At some point I'll figure out what was wrong and post an update.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing `server` directory then as of 0.0.46 requests will always get sent there. See: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2089 I had to hack my own version ember-cli to allow it work as expected.