# Run EmberJS and Django on the same server and port

Tags: django, rest, ember.js, port, server

I want to run EmberJS and Django on the same server for avoid to have cross-domain requests.

So, for exemple, I want to run EmberJS on

> exemple.com:80

and Django REST API on

> exemple.com:80/api/

I normally start ember with command `ember serve --port 80` and a run django with command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. But doing this the two server are on different domain and I have cross doman problems.

How can I do to run all two on same server with same port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way to do this is to run django and ember on different ports, and use a reverse proxy on port 80 to proxy requests to where you need them to go. Nginx is a popular choice (see http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

An example config of what you want

```
server {
  listen 127.0.0.1:8080;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200; # ember server
    # ... additional proxy config
  }
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # django server
    # ... additional proxy config
  }
}
```

Ember CLI can also proxy API request to another server, but I'm not sure about doing it in production.

Comment: Doing this nginx give me this error:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 127.0.0.1:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)

Comment: @user3178668 sorry, change `listen 127.0.0.1:8080;` to `listen 127.0.0.1:80;`

Comment: resolved with changing django port to 8000 and listen port to 80. Also I changed to 127.0.0.1 with exemple.com for make the emberJs application visible from outside

Answer (score 2):

You are running into problems with the content security policy [as described in the ember-cli user guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/#commonissues). You could relax the policy [as described here](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-content-security-policy#options), but I would advise against this.

The `ember server` command is a simple way to set up a fileserver to test your ember code - but it is not meant for production use. Keep in mind that Ember is meant to be compiled into a javascript asset that you would serve via your backend server or host via a CDN (and reference via a script tag in the html/template that your backend app serves).

For django, this means that you would

1. compile you ember app into a js file
2. [put it in django's static dir](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)
3. reference this js file in your index view
4. start django as you would normally (but don't run ember server).

If this is too painful to do in development mode, then I'd recommend playing with the `ember server --proxy` command. It looks like you could do `ember server --proxy 80` and run django on port 80, although [this might not work out-of-the-box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856465/ember-cli-proxy-works-for-get-but-fails-on-put-and-post).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will use this for production I think. 
With ember server --proxy 80 don't work..